# how to validate input fields before inserting into mongodb

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I would like some help for validating input fields before inserting into mongodb.I am creating a registration form in html5 and inserting the values from the from into mongodb using php.I want to validate the field for identity number,south african identity number is 13 digits long , and i want to break it down to get the gender from the identity number.I created a javascript file which validates the length of the field but it still continues after the javascript file has tested the input length.my html5 form is below and its css and the linked javascript file. below is registration form`registration form below register.php`

```
<html>
    <title id="top_title">

    </title>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header id="top_header">
</style>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/register.css"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="validateReg.js" language="javascript"></script>
                <div id="title_image"><marquee behavior="alternate"><h1>Welcome To Tshwane Metro Licensing System</h1></marquee>
                     <img src="MetroPoliceLogo.jpg" alt="not found" id="logo" width="100" height="100">
        </header>

    <body id="main_body">

        <section id="main_section">
                    <form action="process_register.php" method="post" id="id_reg">
                            <table id="login_box">
                                <tr><td><h1 id="login_header">Register</h1></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Username</td><td><input type="email" required="true" id="reg_username" name="reg_username"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" id="reg_password" required="true" name="reg_password"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Name</td><td><input type="text" id="reg_name" required="true" name="reg_name"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Surname</td><td><input type="text" id="reg_surname" required="true" name="reg_surname"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Identity Number</td><td><input type="number" id="reg_idNumber" required="true" name="reg_idNumber" minlength="13" maxlength="13"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Gender</td><td><input type="text" id="reg_gender" required="true" name="reg_gender"></td></tr>
                                <tr><td>Race</td><td><input type="text" id="reg_race" required="true" name="reg_race"></td></tr>
                               <tr><td>Nationality</td><td><input type="text" id="reg_nationality" required="true" name="reg_nationality"></td></tr>
                               <tr><td>Address</td><td><input type="text" id="reg_address" required="true" name="reg_address"></td></tr>
                               <tr><td><input type="submit" id="btnReg" value="Register" name="btnReg" onclick="validateID()"></td></tr>
                            </table>
                    </form>
                <footer>

                </footer>

        </section>
        <aside id="side_news">

                 <img src="signup.jpg" width="150" height="140" >

            </aside>
        <footer id="main_footer">
                <p>Copyright Tshwane Metro Licensing 2016 </p>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

The php script that inserts values in the database is below
process_register.php

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['btnReg']))
    {
           $connection = new Mongo();
           $database = $connection->selectDB('licenseDiskDB');
           $collection = $database->selectCollection('tblusers');

           /*$userQuery = array('reg_username' =>$_POST['reg_username'],
                                'reg_idNumber' =>$_POST['reg_idNumber']);

           $cursor = $collection->findOne($userQuery);
           if($cursor['reg_username']!=$_POST['reg_username'])
           {*/
           $userQuery = array('reg_username' =>$_POST['reg_username']);

           $cursor = $collection->findOne($userQuery);
            $userQueryID = array('reg_idNumber' =>$_POST['reg_idNumber']);

           $IDUser = $collection->findOne($userQueryID);

               if(($cursor)||($IDUser))
               {
                   echo 'Already Registered!';
               }else
               {
                try
                {
                $newUser = array();
                $newUser['reg_username']=$_POST['reg_username'];
                $newUser['reg_password']=$_POST['reg_password'];
                $newUser['reg_name']=$_POST['reg_name'];
                $newUser['reg_surname']=$_POST['reg_surname'];
                $newUser['reg_idNumber']=$_POST['reg_idNumber'];
                $newUser['reg_gender']=$_POST['reg_gender'];
                $newUser['reg_race']=$_POST['reg_race'];
                $newUser['reg_nationality']=$_POST['reg_nationality'];
                $newUser['reg_address']=$_POST['reg_address'];

                $collection->insert($newUser);
                header("Location:http://localhost:8080/phpproject2/reg_success.php");

                } catch (MongoCursorException $ex)
                {
                     die('Insert Failed'.$ex->getMessage());
                }
               }

          /* }else
           {
               echo 'Insert Not Comleted';
           }*/

    }

?>
```

The javascript that tests input for length of 13 digits is below

```
function validateID()
{
    var idNumber = document.getElementById('reg_idNumber');

    if((isNaN(idNumber))===true)
    {
        if(idNumber.toString().length===13)
        {
              alert('Soputh African ID');
        }else
        {
              alert('Incorrect Identity Number length');
              window.location="http://localhost:8080/PhpProject/register.php";
        }
    }else
    {
        alert('Identity Number should not contain characters');

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: isNan will give you a Boolean so no need to add === true.

Comment: also you are only checking the length if it is not a number otherwise it just passes

Comment: also you need to validate on the server as well

Comment: Thanks a million for the inputs